# Failed to enable db2gse spatial commands

Tags: db2, spatial

I created a database called `mapdata` in which I will create a table called `school`. One of the datatypes for one of the columns is `db2gse.ST_Point`. I have tried creating the table `school` with the column with that datatype but it gave me an error saying `db2gse.ST_Point` is an undefined name. So then I figured I had to enable the spatial commands using this statement:

```
db2se enable_db mapdata
```

But that gives me error as well. It says a temporary table space could not be created because there is no available system temporary table space that has a compatible page size.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the [`db2se enable_db` page in the manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.spatial.topics.doc/doc/r0059678.html?lang=en) you will probably notice this, among other things:

> **Usage notes**
>
> Ensure that you have a system temporary table space with a page size of 8 KB or larger and with a minimum size of 500 pages. This is a requirement to run the db2se enable_db command successfully.

The error message tells you that there is no such tablespace. I suspect that your database also does not have a matching bufferpool.

To create a system temporary tablespace you might use the following commands (assuming your database is configured with automatic storage):

```
db2 "create bufferpool bp8k pagesize 8 k" 
db2 "create system temporary tablespace tmpsys8k pagesize 8 k bufferpool bp8k"
```